# R igraph: Color Vertices by column content

Tags: r, igraph, sql-server-2017

I am using igraph to plot a graph from SQL Server. I am providing as input a 3 column table:

```
from   to     color
Node1  NodeA  red
Node1  NodeB  green
Node1  NodeC  blue
Node2  NodeD  red
Node2  NodeE  green
```

My R script looks like this:

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(graphdf)
V(g)$label.cex <- 2
png(filename = "'+@outputFile+'", height = 3000, width = 3000, res = 100);
plot(g, vertex.label.family = "sans", vertex.size = 5)
dev.off()
```

The plot's edges will display with the desired colors, but the vertices themselves do not -- ideally, I want the 'to' vertex to be the color indicated in the 'color' column. I don't care about the 'from's color (it can be the default orange).

I've tried adding this (and variations):

```
V(g)$color <- graphdf[V(g), 3]
```

before the png line, but that produces what appear to be random vertex colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you created your graphdf. Are the columns strings or factors? I will show solutions for both cases.

**graphdf contains strings**

```
library(igraph)

## Create data 
graphdf = read.table(text="from   to     color
Node1  NodeA  red
Node1  NodeB  green
Node1  NodeC  blue
Node2  NodeD  red
Node2  NodeE  green",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
g <- graph.data.frame(graphdf)
```

I will make all nodes be orange, but then adjust the colors for the destination nodes.

```
## Make default color orange
V(g)$color = "orange"
V(g)[graphdf$to]$color = graphdf$color
```

[image: Graph 1]

**graphdf contains factors**

The messier case is if you allowed all of the strings to become factors.  The only difference here is that you must apply `as.character` to all of the factors when you use them .

```
graphdf = read.table(text="from   to     color
Node1  NodeA  red
Node1  NodeB  green
Node1  NodeC  blue
Node2  NodeD  red
Node2  NodeE  green",
header=TRUE)
g <- graph.data.frame(graphdf)

V(g)$color = "orange"
V(g)[as.character(graphdf$to)]$color = as.character(graphdf$color)
plot(g)
```

Comment: Data was provided from a SQL SELECT and as a parameter to sp_execute_external_script, so I didn't know whether it contained factors or not. Turns out it does, second solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, `str(graphdf)` would show you whether they are strings or factors.